# Switch expression function

Tags: functional-programming, swift

I made a bunch of functions and an enumeration, that together allow me to write something like a switch expression. It's not as powerful as Swift switch statements, since it's lacking pattern matching and I don't intend to use this in real code, it was just an experiment. Here is what I got:

```
enum Caze<T: ForwardIndexType where T: Equatable> {
    case RangeCaze(Range<T>)
    case ArrayCaze([T])

    func contains(elem: T) -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case let .RangeCaze(r):
            return r.contains(elem)
        case let .ArrayCaze(arr):
            return arr.contains(elem)
        }
    }
}


func caze<T: ForwardIndexType, R where T: Equatable>(vals: T..., @autoclosure(escaping) ret f: () -> R) -> (Caze<T>, () -> R) {
    return (.ArrayCaze(vals), f)
}

func caze<T: ForwardIndexType, R where T: Equatable>(vals: Range<T>, @autoclosure(escaping) ret f: () -> R) -> (Caze<T>, () -> R) {
    return (.RangeCaze(vals), f)
}

func caze<T: Equatable, R>(vals: T..., @autoclosure(escaping) ret f: () throws -> R) -> ([T], () throws -> R) {
    return (vals, f)
}


func schwitch<T: ForwardIndexType, R where T: Equatable>(value: T, _ cases: (Caze<T>, () -> R)..., @autoclosure def: () throws -> R) rethrows -> R {
    for (vals, f) in cases {
        if vals.contains(value) {
            return f()
        }
    }
    return try def()
}

func schwitch<T: Equatable, R>(value: T, _ cases: ([T], () -> R)..., @autoclosure def: () throws -> R) rethrows -> R {
    for (vals, f) in cases {
        if vals.contains(value) {
            return f()
        }
    }
    return try def()
}
```

This allows me to write code like:

```
schwitch(5, // results in "lol"
    caze(0, ret: "hello"),
    caze(1, 2, ret: "test"),
    caze(3..<7, ret: "lol"),
    def: "nop")

schwitch("helloo", //results in "nop"
    caze("hello", "Hello", ret: "test"),
    def: "nop")
```

I think there are a few problems with this though.

1. There is quite a bit of code duplication due to a few nearly identical functions being needed.
2. The closure sent to the `caze` functions are escaping, though they are intended to never actually escape beyond a very defined scope.
3. If code in a `caze` function throws, it doesn't get rethrown.
4. I also considered an alternative implementation for the `schwitch` functions but am worried that it takes brevity a bit too far:

   ```
   (cases.filter{$0.contains(value)}.first ?? def)()
   ```

Are there any ways to improve on these 4 points and are there any other things that I missed or could have done better?

Comment: I have started an effort to improve my own code but have hit a road block since Xcode hangs up on my code. I have posted [a question on SO about it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37673810/3684713).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. There is quite a bit of code duplication due to a few nearly identical functions being needed.

This is probably the biggest issue and the one I'll be addressing here.

The two `schwitch` functions have identical bodies, this is a major code smell. The only difference between the two is the generic constraints on `T` and the type `T` is wrapped up in (`Array` and `Caze` repectively). You don't actually care that `T`conforms to `ForwardIndexType` in the `schwitch` function and the only way I was using both `Caze` and `Array` was by calling `contains` on them (with identical signatures). This clearly calls for a protocol. And I didn't even need to declare one myself. the `contains` function I was using is declared in `SequenceType`, a protocol both `Array` and `Range` conform to. So here's what the new (and only) `schwitch` function will look like:

```
func schwitch<S: SequenceType, R where S.Generator.Element: Equatable>(value: S.Generator.Element, _ cases: (S, () -> R)..., @autoclosure def: () -> R) -> R {
    for (vals, f) in cases {
        if vals.contains(value) {
            return f()
        }
    }
    return def()
}
```

<sub>You will notice that function is now missing a `rethrows`, [the swift compiler hangs up on that due to a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37689910/3684713).</sub>

This also allowed me to get rid of the `Caze` enum and only have two `caze` functions, one that takes any amount of values and one that takes a range:

```
func caze<T: Equatable, R>(vals: T..., @autoclosure(escaping) ret f: () -> R) -> (AnySequence<T>, () -> R) {
    return (AnySequence(vals), f)
}

func caze<T, R where T: Equatable, T: ForwardIndexType>(range: Range<T>, @autoclosure(escaping) ret f: () -> R) -> (AnySequence<T>, () -> R) {
    return (AnySequence(range), f)
}
```

I've made both functions return an `AnySequence<T>` instead of more concrete type, I think that makes sense, considering how the results are used, but it's really up to you if you maybe want to return `Array<T>` and `Range<T>` instead.

I can still use my function exactly as I did before.